# Checking Username in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

I have a small application somewhat like Facebook username. When i go to the link `localhost/pretty-urls/index.php?id=100000001` I will be redirected to `localhost/pretty-urls/myusername` using `.htaccess` successfully.

But before I get redirected, I need to check the id if it is already in the MySQL database. If so, then that's the time I will redirect it.

My question is how can I check if the username `myusername` exists and it is not a directory or a file if for example the user will input `localhost/pretty-urls/myusername` ? If doesn't exist in the database, not a directory or a file will then redirect it to a 404 page.

BTW, this is my `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

When I try `localhost/pretty-url/usernotexist` i am not redirected to 404 page but when i put something like this `localhost/pretty-url/usernotexist/dfdg` then that's the time I am redirected. When in fact the username `usernotexist` doesn't exist in my DB. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Htaccess cannot have rules for your database, you have to check using PHP code in this case. Hence the redirect has to be made still, even if different.

Comment: This is potentially a big security hole as the user could input an valid userid he wanted and be redirected to the myusername page

Comment: If he use a valid userid, then it will be redirected to a profile page who has a userid like that. But, I also limit something on that though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check your database from the htaccess file, what I would do is use php to check the username and redirect using a header() call.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: [Of course it's possible](http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/). Just extremely not recommended.

Comment: I know I can't check db using htaccess. But is it helpful to know if `usernotexist` a file or a directory?